# Inconsistent Number Format with Locale de_AT on different Java versions

Tags: java

When I run the following code on different Java versions, I get inconsistent results:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Locale locale =  new Locale("de", "AT");
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        decimalFormat.applyPattern("###,##0.00");
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(1000));
    }
}
```

I'd expect the result to be `1.000,00`

- Result with Java 1.8.0_66: `1.000,00`
- Result with Java 9.0.1: `1?000,00`
- Result with Java 10.0.1: `1?000,00`
- Result with Java 11.0.4: `1 000,00`
- Result with Java 11.0.4: `1 000,00`

Changing the Locale to
`Locale locale = new Locale("de");`

- Result with Java 1.8.0_66: `1.000,00`
- Result with Java 9.0.1: `1.000,00`
- Result with Java 10.0.1: `1.000,00`
- Result with Java 11.0.4: `1.000,00`
- Result with Java 11.0.4: `1.000,00`

Is this a bug or what is the reason for the inconsistent results?

Comment: Btw: I'm reasonably sure that the `?` in the output for Java 9 & 10 is an artifact of how you output the result (i.e. the encoding you use on the console). As the anser by @kutschkem suggests, that's probably meant to be a U+2009 character and your console uses an encoding that doesn't support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 9, the [source for the localization data](https://openjdk.org/jeps/252) changed from "JRE" to "CLDR", which is Unicode Consortium's Common Locale Data Repository.

As far as I understand, in this data set, the separator for de_AT is a thin space (U+2009). The ? you see is probably due to whatever encoding you use in your console not being able to show that unicode character.

In Java 11, the data source was changed yet again, [to CLDR-33](https://blog.netcetera.com/unexpected-incompatibilities-with-java-11-81ed929cc091). I can't tell what version it was before. This changes again some locales.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibweise_von_Zahlen#Tausendertrennzeichen, German language) Austria (ÖNORM A 1080) allows using a "." or a "Blank" for grouping numbers, as long as this is done without line breaks. A non-breaking-space (since Java 11) seems to be a better solution in the context.